# A purchased and downloaded iTunes television show will not play

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, video

A heads up - I am a complete layman with absolutely no knowledge of operating system or hardware stuff aside from the fact that I have no knowledge of it. Any answers that are given I would prefer to be in simple, nontechnical English.

Here is my quarry: I have purchased a season pass for Gotham on iTunes and have downloaded the newest episode. Upon completion of the download, I pressed the play button. The screen was completely black, there was no audio, the progress bar wasn't moving and the show was registered as playing. I have no idea what version of the apple operating system I am using and the only knowledge I have of the hardware is that it is a MacBook Air that is at least two years old.

I have already tried several things in an attempt to get it to work, to no avail. They are, in order of when I tried them:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the show
- Closing and reopening the iTunes application
- Turning off and back on my laptop
- Unauthorizing and reauthorizing my computer
- Waiting it out for twelve hours

Nothing I have done has in any way altered the problem which presents itself when I try to watch the show. I have no problems watching videos on YouTube; it is simply shows purchased via iTunes which refuse to work properly. This problem has not occurred prior to today, though when I tried to watch a different show (I forget off the top of my head which one I clicked) that didn't work either.

Since I posted this 24 hours ago I have managed to successfully use iTunes to play music. I downloaded Star Wars episode I and tried watching that, but alas, movies do not work either. The 30-second bit that plays as a trailer for the new episode of a television show, however, did manage to play succesfully after a minute of there being a black screen like what I described, leading me to maybe suspect that this is a buffering problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the App Store and found iTunes update to version 12.6.1.  Ran the update and now my TV shows are playing.  Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: Mine automatically updates (I think) and is currently running 12.6.1.25, according to the "about iTunes" button that appears if you bring your mouse up to the top part of the screen where you can see the battery and time and whatnot and then click the "iTunes" button.

Comment: I just found the app store and I downloaded the system update to that same number that you mentioned; it wasn't an iTunes update though.